# Equivalent functors

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. If $F: Mod \to Mod$ is a left exact functor and $R^iF(E)=0$ where $E$ is injective module. Assume that $F(-) \cong Hom(M,-)$, can we infer the $i-th$ right devired functors $R^iF(-)\cong Ext^i(M,-)$?

Comment: You can define $Ext$ by taking derived functors of $Hom$ in either
variable. If you are using the second variable, it's tautologically true (see Andreas Blass' answer). So I suspect you might be 
defining it via a projective  resolution of $M$ (or via Yoneda or...) Then there is something to prove, but this can be
found in many homological algebra texts. I'm sure someone can elaborate, but it would be good to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For example, if you compute right derived functors by injective resolutions, then naturality of the isomorphism between $F$ and $\text{Hom}(M,-)$ will ensure that you have an isomorphism between the two complexes whose cohomology groups give you the two derived functors.